# Weird CSS Sidebar Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, firebug, positioning

[Here is the site in question](http://reneewarren.com/category/blog/)

I've got the sidebar working on any other page of the site except for this one; all of the pages have the same template. The sidebar right now is doing the old "go under the content".

When I try and edit its positioning in Firebug to anything but relative and then change it back to relative, it snaps back into place just fine. However, changes I've made in the code do nothing.

The issue started to appear when I added youtuve videos to the posts.

Any ideas beyond quickly changing the positioning with Jquery?

Comment: what browsers show the problem ? it looks fine to me in FF, Opera, Chrome, IE7 ..

Comment: Fine in Safari 4. Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Hey @Wes, I posted an answer and have tested it on a ton of browsers via the Adobe Browser lab. It works, for sure, so it shouldn't be another rabbit trail for you to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the sidebar where it was (below the `<div id="left">`) and just change one CSS rule, and add another:

```
/* layout.css Line 310 */
#content {
  display: block; /* Changed from 'table' */
  overflow: hidden; /* Keeps 'left' and 'sidebar' from overflowing
}
```

**Tested to work**: Firefox  2.0 Win, 3.0 Mac/Win, 3.5 Mac; Safari 4; IE6, IE7, IE8; Chrome 3 Win

Comment: cha-ching! What an odd issue. Thank you so much for your help, you really went above and beyond! 

Could you take down that temp site? Dont want to have dupe content on the net. 

Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Wes Glad I could help, the temp page has been removed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you remove `position:relative` from `#content`? Also, I'm able to duplicate the problem on FF3.0.17 XP

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the `position:relative` on `#sidebar` is what is screwing it up. Try changing it to `position: static` on the sidebar id.

Comment: I was hoping this would do it but no luck. Works with firebug but not when I save a re-load the css.

Comment: yeah, now i see. I created a local version of your site. Removing all of position: relatives seems to do no good. It's definitely something that's being triggered by the YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some mising closing tags: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of reneewarren.com/category/blog/ - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//reneewarren.com/category/blog/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). And try using a plugin to do a valid embed of flash: [WordPress › Kimili Flash Embed « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kimili-flash-embed/).

Comment: Ah, I was missing a closing Div tag but once validated the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the sidebar markup before the content markup.

Comment: That worked! Not the best solution due to SEO but it works. I'd like to hear if anyone else has a suggestion, if not I'll award you the answer.

thanks again :)

Comment: Since you are using a fixed width layout, you can float the sidebar to the left as well. That will solve your problem without reordering your content.

Comment: Floating right is only for design, when a bot crawls a site they disable all styling leaving the sidebar links above all of the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a high z-index ?